# Java Mail IPv6 localhost EHLO

Tags: java, email, ipv6

I am working on a Java servlet that sends email messages over SMTP using javax.mail (1.4.7). My test location is connected to the SMTP server via IPv6, while my production environment is IPv4.

Login to the SMTP server from the IPv6 environment fails at the (second) EHLO command (after STARTTLS). It is my understanding that in IPv6 context, the 'localhost' name given with the EHLO should be IPv6 address between square brackets, but in IPv4 context the (fully qualified) hostname of the client should be used.

I checked the exchange between my Thunderbird client and this SMTP server (using Wireshark), and indeed it sends the IPv6 address after EHLO.

However java mail sends the hostname after EHLO both in IPv4 and in IPv6 contexts. In IPv6 this fails.

The two obvious workarounds available are:
- setting the property mail.smtp.ehlo=false
- setting the property mail.smtp.localhost=[IPv6:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:x:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]

Both these workarounds are successful. However they require me to use a different setup/configuration depending on where the servlet runs.

Questions;
- is the IPv6 EHLO not yet supported in java mail?
- is there an elegant way to whether the connection is either IPv4 or IPv6 and adjust the setup accordingly?